# Grails regex for validating a URL

Tags: regex, url, grails

I am trying to validate a url entered by a user in Grails.

```
Class userURL
{
String url_value
static contraints = {
url_value matches:/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/
}
}
```

But it shows me error: invalid symbol. I am not sure why it's happening because the regex is correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Hey Amal. It first showed me the error invalid symbol at line 5 column 41. But on recompilation, it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do?:

```
 String url_value
 static contraints = {
    url_value url:true
 }
```

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/url.html

It is likely to be much less error prone.

Comment: I did this only. Thanks :)